# Can't run xmlHttp.responseXML on a local server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm learning AJAX and XML this days. Recently I have ran into a stupid problem.

I try to build a simple program that will show me in a `<div>` all that I input into an input box.
For some reason when I try to use the `.responseXML` property my program won't run. Note that when I use the `.responseText` everything works fine.

**my html code** :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="foodstore.js"></script>
    </head>
    <h3> the chuff bucket </h3>
    <body onload="process()">

        <input type="text" id="userInput"/>
        <div id="underInput"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**my php code:**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>';
echo '<response>';
$food=$_GET['food'];
echo $food;
echo '</response>';
?>
```

**my js code:**

```
// JavaScript Document
var xmlHttp= createXmlHttpRequestObject();



function createXmlHttpRequestObject(){
    var xmlHttp;


    if(window.ActiveXObject){
        try{
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }catch(e){
            xmlHttp = false;
    }


    } else {
        try{
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }catch(e){
            xmlHttp = false;
        }
    }

    if(!xmlHttp){
        alert("cant create object");
    }else{
        return xmlHttp;
    }
}



function process(){
    var x = xmlHttp.readyState
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==0||xmlHttp.readyState==4){

        food = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("userInput").value)
        xmlHttp.open("GET","foodstore.php?food=" + food , true);
        x=xmlHttp.readyState;
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange= handleServerResponse;
        xmlHttp.send(null);

    }else{
        setTimeout('process()',1000);
    }   
 }


function handleServerResponse(){

    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
        if(xmlHttp.status==200){

        var xmlResponse= xmlHttp.responseXML;
            root = xmlResponse.documentElement;
            alert(root.firstchild);
            //message= root.firstChild.data;

            document.getElementById("underInput").innerHTML= '<span        style="color:blue">' + xmlResponse + '</span>';
            setTimeout('process()', 1000);
        }else{
            alert('not working');
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to the helpers.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried with jQuery ? It may be easier to do. You can specify the data type

```
function ajaxJQueryRequest(url,afterReqFunction){
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "xml"
        });
    request.done(function(msg) {
            afterReqFunction(msg);
        });
    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
        });
}
```

Comment: In handleServerResponse() try to do : 
console.log(xmlHttp.responseXML); and tell us what it is the console

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I found the bug.
I entered the url of the php file (that sending the response to the html) and got the following error:
"This page contains the following errors:

error on line 2 at column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document"

after I deleted the blank space at the top of my php I received a new error, after I fixed the new error everything worked like a charm... thanks a lot!!